# EPiServer Commerce 7 Simple Url

Tags: episerver-7

In EPiServer CMS 7, the pages that come from EPiServer Commerce 7 has the property "Simple Url", but it is not possible to change this. In fact, there is not even a text field to change this although a heading for the field is there (see image). Is there a way to enable this for the commerse pages? While the image is in Swedish, anyone with EPiServer experience should know what i'm refering to.

[image: Commerce]

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch to the default language to be able to change this

Comment: @ShauryaChats - In the context of EPiServer, this is an answer.  I can't confirm of it's right (I don't have EPi Commerce), but I can't think of plenty of EPiServer questions where this is the right answer.